Error in configuration process, project files may be invalid in CMake
I have been trying to add glfw 3.4 libraries using CMake for an OpenGl project that I'm doing and it brings this Error information:
CMake Error: The source directory "C:/glfw-3.4.bin.WIN64" does not appear to contain cMakeLists.txt.

STEPS THAT I TOOK BEFORE THIS ERROR OCCURRED:

I downloaded glfw 3.4 pre-compiled binaries for 64bits Windows
computer system with this link: https://www.glfw.org/download.html

Then I downloaded Cmake installer for 64 bits Windows computer system with this link: https://cmake.org/download/

Then I installed CMake to this file directory: C:\Program Files

Then I added the file directory of the CMake GUI application to the Environment system variables path through the advanced system settings.

Then I extracted the glfw 3.4 folder using WINRAR since it was zipped folder to this file directory: C:\(C disk drive location)

Then I open the CMake GUI application and did the following:

I added the main folder which contains the glfw 3.4 libraries to
where is the source code option section with this file directory: C:/glfw-3.4.bin.WIN64
Then I created a folder called "Build" inside the main folder which contains glfw 3.4 libraries.
I added the build folder to the where to build the binaries option with this file directory: C:/glfw-3.4.bin.WIN64/Build
Then I clicked on the configure option. I chosed MinGw Makefiles in specify the generator for this project option since CodeBlocks is the IDE I'm using.
Then I clicked on the use default native compilers option and I clicked the finish option.




The last parameter to cmake should point to the source directory, which contains CMakeLists.txt file. You don't show your exact command, so it is impossible to be more specific.

I'm using the CMake GUI application to add  the glfw 3.4 libraries and can you specify what I should I do to be more specific I'm kinda new to this so I've not used any command line yet,thanks for answering me I really appreciate it.

In CMake GUI you specify a source directory. Make sure that given directory contains CMakeLists.txt file. If you need more detailed advice, then firstly [edit] your question post to include exact steps you are performing and exact error message you got. You current description is very vague. And taking into account that you are new in CMake, that description could mean almost anything.

I just edited my post it includes all the steps I did before the error occurred.

"I downloaded glfw 3.4 pre-compiled binaries" - You already have GLFW libraries. Just use them in your project. Building is needed only in case you have sources.
